# Set background colors for the cells of multiple columns based on string contents using gt package

Tags: r, gt, gtextras

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
res1 <- c("true", "true", "false", "true", "false")
res2 <- c("false", NA, NA, "true", "true")
df <- data.frame(id, res1, res2)

df %>% 
  gt()
```

Out:

[image]

For columns `res1` and `res2`, let's say if value content are `true`s, I'll need to highlight that cell with `red` background color, if `false`s, highlight with `green` color, for other cases, keep their colors as original.

How could I achieve that using gt package in R?

Note: the example code and outcome from the link below are for **values**, not **strings** as this case.

[image]

**References:**

https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/data_color.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [as per manual - *data_color*](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/data_color.html):

```
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = c("res1", "res2"),
    colors = c("green", "red"),
    apply_to = "fill",
    autocolor_text = FALSE)
```

[image]