# Set background color if one cell's (of multiple columns) content is specific string using gt package

Tags: r, gt

With code below (from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755381/set-background-colors-for-the-cells-of-multiple-columns-based-on-string-contents)), we can set background colors for the cells of multiple columns based on string contents using `gt` package:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
res1 <- c("true", "true", "false", "true", "false")
res2 <- c("false", NA, NA, "true", "true")
df <- data.frame(id, res1, res2)

df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = c("res1", "res2"),
    colors = c("green", "red"),
    apply_to = "fill",
    autocolor_text = FALSE)
```

Out:

[image]

Now let's say I will need to **set red background color only if content is `true` for columns `res1` and `res2`**, if it's other values such as `false` or `NA`, just keep as original, which means I hope to highlight `true` cells for these two columns. How could I do that? Thanks.

**References:**

https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_style.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gt::tab_style` you could do:

```
library(gt)
library(magrittr)

df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "red")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(res1, res2),
      rows = res1 == "true" & res2 == "true"
    )
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** In case of multiple columns you could basically create the conditions like so. Basic idea it to first create a string containing the condition on which rows to target and using `!!rlang::parse_expr` to evaluate that string inside `gt::cell_body`:

Note: I added two more columns to your df to make the example more realistic.

```
library(gt)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(id, res1, res2, res3 = res1, res4 = res2)


cols <- paste0("res", 1:4)
conditions <- lapply(cols, function(x) "true")
names(conditions) <- cols 

rows <- paste(glue::glue("{.col} == '{.value}'", .col = names(conditions), .value = conditions), collapse = " & ")

df %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "red")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = all_of(cols),
      rows = !!rlang::parse_expr(rows)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing this solution, but there is one issue, if I have a dataframe with many columns (20 columns for example) rather than only 2 columns, `rows = ` will be followed by the code very long.

Comment: I See. Will have a look. I would guess that it should be possible to simplify that.

Comment: I just made an edit to show you one possible option.