# How to customize background colors based on (characters, NA) contents in multiple columns using gt

Tags: r, gt

Based on the code and data from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755381/set-background-colors-for-the-cells-of-multiple-columns-based-on-string-contents), we can set background colors for the cells of multiple columns based on string contents using `gt` package:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
res1 <- c("true", "true", "false", "true", "false")
res2 <- c("false", NA, NA, "true", "true")
res3 <- c("true", NA, NA, "true", "true")
df <- data.frame(id, res1, res2, res3)

df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = c("res1", "res2", 'res3'),
    colors = c("green", "red", 'gray'),
    apply_to = "fill",
    autocolor_text = FALSE)
```

[image]

But as you may noticed, for `res3`, the color for `true` is `green` instead of `red` as in other two columns. If I hope to set `red` for `true`, `green` for `false` and `gray` for `NA`, for these 3 columns, if in case, they have other values such as `yes`, `no`, etc., just keep as original.

How could we solve this problem? Many thanks at advance.

**Update1:** an alternative solution with `tab_style()`, but not concise:

```
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'red')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res1,
      rows = res1 == "true"
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'red')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res2,
      rows = res2 == "true"
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'red')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res3,
      rows = res3 == "true"
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'green')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res1,
      rows = res1 == "false"
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'green')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res2,
      rows = res2 == "false"
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'green')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res3,
      rows = res3 == "false"
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'gray')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res1,
      rows = res1 == NA
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'gray')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res2,
      rows = res2 == NA
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'gray')
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = res3,
      rows = res3 == NA
    )
  )
```

[image]

**Update2:** How to correctly set gray color for NA cells?

```
cols <- c('res1', 'res2', 'res3')
df %>% 
  # mutate_each_(funs(factor(.)), cols)
  mutate_at(cols, factor) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = cols,
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      palette = c('green', 'red', 'gray'),
      domain = c('false', 'true', NA)
    ),
    apply_to = "fill",
    autocolor_text = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

**Update3:** I set `palette = c("green", "red", 'yellow'), domain = c("false", "true", '-')`, why it's not shown `green` for `false`, `red` for `true`, and `yellow` for `-`?

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
res1 <- c("true", "true", "false", "true", "false")
res2 <- c("false", NA, NA, "true", "-")
res3 <- c("true", NA, NA, "true", "true")
df <- data.frame(id, res1, res2, res3)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(cols, factor) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = cols,
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      palette = c("green", "red", 'yellow'),
      domain = c("false", "true", '-'),
      na.color = 'gray'
    ),
    apply_to = "fill",
    autocolor_text = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

**References:**

[Set background color if one cell's (of multiple columns) content is specific string using gt package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901587/set-background-color-if-one-cells-of-multiple-columns-content-is-specific-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to **Update 2**, the version with character strings, this should work:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(cols, factor) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = cols,
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      palette = c("green", "red"),
      domain = c("false", "true")
    ),
    apply_to = "fill",
    autocolor_text = FALSE
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, let's say if I wanna set `yellow` color for `NA`s? How could we do that?

Comment: Just add `na.color = "yellow"` to the `col_factor` call.

Comment: Rather than color names use hex values (i.e., `"#FFFF00"` for "yellow"). Can you post a sample of your real data?

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, after I carefully re-check my code, I found I've made a mistake in the code. However I find a new issue which I added as **update3** in the question, which is, the color palette and domain's orders are not coordinated. It's quite confusing.

Comment: Are there four values now? TRUE, FALSE, NA and "-"?

Comment: Yes. `c('true', 'false', NA, '-')`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to store your logical values as character strings. If you use `TRUE` and `FALSE` values instead, `gt()` works as designed to give you the table coloring you want.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
res1 <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
res2 <- c(FALSE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE)
res3 <- c(TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(id, res1, res2, res3)

df2 %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = c(res1, res2, res3),
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      palette = c("green", "red"),
      domain = c(FALSE, TRUE)
    ),
    apply_to = "fill",
    autocolor_text = FALSE
  )
```

If there's some reason you have to have the logicals as character strings you'll need to convert them to a factor and adjust the `domain` argument in `data_color()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, `col_factor` is the function I'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. I had only read about `data_color()` so it was a good way to dig into it.

Comment: Sorry to confuse u with `true`, `false`, in my real data it's character strings, maybe I should use for example `yes`, `no` instead of `true`, `false`.

Comment: If you decide to stick with the character strings just use factors and change `data_color` to  `domain = c("false", "true")` (or whatever words you want).

Comment: I added new code and output in the end of question, I didn't succeed in setting `gray` color for `NA` cells, do u mind have a look?

Comment: After converting `NA` to factor, it become `<NA>`, but I set `domain = c('false', 'true', NA)` or `domain = c('false', 'true', <NA>)`, it didn't work out.

Comment: I'll have a look.